Why does my powershell keep showing an unrelated error?
When I'm using Powershell, and I my command is not recognized, it always shows these extra 2 CommandNotFoundException's (CategoryInfo & FullyQualifiedErrorId). It's not blocking anything, but just annoying. Does anybody know why they are showing? And how I can stop it from showing up each time?
Thanks!
PS C:\Users\jeroe> thisIsATest
thisIsATest : The term 'thisIsATest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ thisIsATest
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (thisIsATest:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I'm pretty new to using command lines, but each time I type a wrong command, some extra exceptions are thrown and shown.

they are just the error message telling you WHAT is wrong exactly so you can fix it. If you find it bothersome... you are in good company in fact in Powershell 7 the message has been reduced to only the first line.

Those are not "extra errors", they're part of the same error record

What is thisIsATest? Is it a filename that has an extension? .exe, .bat, .cmd, .ps1, .py, etc.? Is it a PowerShell function name? Is it a PowerShell alias? This error message is PowerShell's way of saying "Bad command or file name."

You entered a command thisIsATest that is not known to the PowerShell. If you intend to use a PowerShell command, use an existing command. If you define somehow the thisIsATest cmdlet, function, script or alias, it' useful to add this information in the question.

@lit the 'thisIsATest' command was just an example of a command, to show the errors I always recieve.



What you're seeing is the multiline representation of a single error, using the 'NormalView' setting of the $ErrorView preference variable.

In Windows PowerShell, this is the default setting, and the only way to get a single-line representation is to choose the 'CategoryView' setting; unfortunately, however, this representation typically does NOT provide enough information to identify the error; e.g.:
$ErrorView = 'CategoryView'; 1 / 0

yields:
# Note: The error *message* is missing.
NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException


Fortunately, PowerShell (Core) 7 now defaults to a new setting, 'ConciseView', that is both (typically) single-line and usually provides enough information:
# Note: 'ConciseView' is the default in PowerShell 7
1 / 0

yields:
# In PowerShell 7
RuntimeException: Attempted to divide by zero.


Additionally, PowerShell 7 has a 'DetailedView' setting (undocumented as of this writing), which provides even more details than 'NormalView', and uses the same display format as the PowerShell 7-only Get-Error cmdlet; you can use the latter to examine errors after the fact.




If you want to emulate the PowerShell 7-only 'ConciseView' setting in Windows PowerShell, you can override the built-in formatting data for the System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord .NET type that is used to represent PowerShell errors:

This GitHub comment shows this approach (but note that the format doesn't exactly match PowerShell 7's ConciseView; adapt as needed); it was created in the context of discussing the changes that led to the introduction of 'ConciseView' in PowerShell 7.
If you place the linked code in your $PROFILE file, it will take effect in all future sessions.

